# SQL query for finding duplicate and get others values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having

Here is my issue. I would like to find duplicate 'code ifls' and get the different warehouses where I get this duplicated code

This is how the table looks like:

```
| code ifls | warehouse | 
|    4013   |        1  | 
|    4013   |        2  | 
|    4013   |        3  | 
|    4014   |        4  | 
|    4014   |        5  | 
|    4015   |        5  |
```

The result should look like this:

```
| code ifls | warehouse | warehouse | warehouse |
|    4013   |     1     |     2     |     3     | 
|    4014   |     4     |     5     |           |
```

I tried that request but without success...

```
SELECT code ifls as ifls, (SELECT warehouse FROM catalogue WHERE code ifls= ifls) 
FROM catalogue GROUP BY code ifls HAVING COUNT(code ifls) > 1
```

How would you express this in a SQL query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177816/combine-multiple-child-rows-into-one-row-mysql-without-hardcoding-or-min-max-val/36178292#36178292

Comment: You can't easily have a dynamic number of columns like that. Is there a set maximum number of columns you need, or are you trying to generate columns as required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is probably the simplest way to do what you're trying to do without complicating things using dynamic columns;

```
SELECT `code ifls`, GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse) warehouses
FROM myTable
GROUP BY `code ifls`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1355d/1).

It basically delivers a comma separated list of warehouses for each `code ilfs`, but the `HAVING` limits it to rows with more than one warehouse.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I need! Thx Joachim!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect and group_concat

```
select `code ifls`, group_concat(warehouse) 
from table  
where `code ifls` in (
    select `code ifls`, count(*)  
    from table 
    group by `code ifls`
    having count(*) > 1
)
group by `code ifls`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code-

```
SELECT `code ifls`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse),',',1) AS warehouse_1, 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse SEPARATOR ''))) < 1,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse),',',2),',',-1)) AS warehouse_2, 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse SEPARATOR ''))) < 2,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse),',',-1)) AS warehouse_3 
FROM `catalogue`
GROUP BY `code ifls`;
```